# How to set a item selection and the first visible?

Tags: android, listview, selection

I want to set the first visible item when I press some key or button(it is a function like `page up` and `page down`), I use `setSelection(position)`, but I find that when I use this method, the selected selected item is not at the first visible position.

for example, a ListView like this:

```
-----visible-----
1(this is selected)
2
3
4
5
-----visible-----
-----invisible----
6
7
8
9
10
-----invisible-----
```

when I press page down, it becomes

```
----invisible
1
2
3
-----invisible-----
-----visible-----
4
5
6(this is selected)
7
8
-----visible-----
-----invisible-----
9
10
-----invisible-----
```

what I want is:

```
-----invisible-----
1
2
3
4
5
-----invisible-----
-----visible-----
6(this is selected)
7
8
9
10
-----visible-----
```

How can I setSlection and make this item this first visible?

---

here is the code:

```
selection = mDetailsListView.getSelectedItemPosition() + getVisibleCount() - 1;
selection = selection > mDetailsListView.getCount() ? mDetailsListView
        .getCount() - 1 : selection;
mDetailsListView.setSelection(selection);

private int getVisibleCount() {
    return mDetailsListView.getLastVisiblePosition() -mDetailsListView
                .getFirstVisiblePosition() + 1;
}
```

Comment: post the code where you set the selection

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin code is added